# Global Variable not reading in Lexer function

Tags: c, flex-lexer

Working on a compiler, and I want to print out a symbol table. I have a node structure and I need to access the global variable "lineCount". When I try to print it in the idPush function, I get a segmentation fault. My goal is to get the nodes either housed in an array, or linked together, and then print the table.

I have tried to print it elsewhere in the code, but the fault arises. I run a text file that I will include, it is very short just to make sure it is working.

```
%option noyywrap
%{

    #include <stdio.h>  /* needed for printf() */
    #define YY_DECL int yylex()
    #define STRINGMAX 25
    struct Node* nodes[100];
        int lineCount = 0;


    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        char type[STRINGMAX];
        char wordv[STRINGMAX];

        struct Node *next;
    };
        void idPush(const char *new_data, char *typel){
        // Allocate memory for node 
        struct Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
        strncpy(new_node->wordv, new_data, STRINGMAX-1); 
        new_node->wordv[STRINGMAX-1] = '\0';
        strncpy(new_node->type, typel, STRINGMAX);

        printf("allocated new node space\n");


        printf(lineCount);
        nodes[lineCount] = new_node;

        if(lineCount > 0){
            cleanNodes(nodes);
      }
        getData(new_node);

    }
```

The output for lineCount should be zero as it is the first pass of the code, but I get the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:

```
printf(lineCount);
```

The first argument to `printf` is a format string that describes what you want to print.  Because the type you're passing to the function is not what it expects, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case results in a crash.

If you want to print an integer, use the `%d` format specifier.

```
printf("%d\n", lineCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` takes an argument of type `char*` as its first argument. You're passing it an integer (and if you didn't get at least a warning about that, you should increase your compiler's warning level - and if you did, you should stop ignoring warnings). Converting that integer to a `char*` is not going to result in an address of a valid string (especially since it starts out as 0, so you'll get a null pointer), so passing it to `printf`, which dereferences it, will invoke undefined behavior. In this case, the undefined behavior exhibits as a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.